# HttpURLconnection no android:

Tags: java, android, http

Olá , estou tentando obter o código de resposta http , e estou usando esse código :

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();

int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

O problema é o seguinte : getResponseCode(); obtém o código uma vez só ? , ou ao chamá-lo ele atualizara o status com o code atual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cada vez que você chamar ele retornará o status code:

```
 HTTP/1.0 200 OK
 HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Ou se não for uma resposta HTTP válida ele retornará -1.